# PHP - format path urls

Tags: php, url, path

In my PHP project, I have an url path string returned like:

```
 {
  "data": {
    "image": "https:\/\/uploads-ssl.webflow.com\/5f6a30b165eb44156b3bc6ca_N%20GRAPH%20SETTINGS.png",
    "url": "https:\/\/www.uhub.io\/"
   }
}
```

What I would like to accomplish is for this two paths to be without `\` and `%` ..

How can I format them?

I know this question is already answer but I can not find right PHP fucntion for it.

Code:

```
$encodeData = json_encode($metaData);

return json_decode($encodeData, true);
```

and the problem persists.

Comment: The backslashes are part of the JSON formatting. When you call `json_decode()` they'll be removed.

Comment: The `%` are necessary for URL encoding of certain punctuation characters. You shouldn't remove them.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the problem. Show how you're creating `$metaData` and how these escaped characters cause an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Working Solution:

The PHP Function [stripcslashes()](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.stripcslashes.php) does what you need: Removes the escaping character `\` where it's not needed.

The %.. characters are part of URL Encoding, so don't remove them.

Here is a working solution how to remove the `\` from your object:

```
<?php

$data = [
    'image' => "https:\/\/uploads-ssl.webflow.com\/5f6a30b165eb44156b3bc6ca_N%20GRAPH%20SETTINGS.png",
    'url' => "https:\/\/www.uhub.io\/"
];

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = stripcslashes($value);
}

print_r($data);
```

---

## Old answer:

This is a JSON String and the backslashes are part of **JSON formatting**.

Remove it by decoding it:

```
$data = '{
  "data": {
    "image": "https:\/\/uploads-ssl.webflow.com\/5f6a30b165eb44156b3bc6ca_N%20GRAPH%20SETTINGS.png",
    "url": "https:\/\/www.uhub.io\/"
   }
}';
$rawData = json_decode($data, true);
```

`$rawData` is now:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [image] => https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f6a30b165eb44156b3bc6ca_N%20GRAPH%20SETTINGS.png
            [url] => https://www.uhub.io/
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for replay but output is "Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given"," @EinLinuus

Comment: Then you passed an array to the function and not the JSON string. If you have an array, try to encode it first and then decode it. json_encode($your_array)

Comment: Yes and it returns the output but still with the same problem in url paths. @EinLinuus

Comment: I'm very sorry for my wrong answer. I found the function you'll need for that and edited my answer.